# Calculate the % contribution in total output by each Line No. in crystal report 2010

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

[image: % contribution calculation table]

This is the table i have generated by using crystal report 2010.

I need to calculate the % contribution of each line in the total Good Lgth(Mtr).

For example: if line no. is 6012 then its % contribution in total production must be (155973/1338595)*100 = 11.65 %.Same as for all the lines.

But '1338595' value is only generated when crystal report is printing the last row and i required this value in the first row of % contribution column to get a correct result.

Right now it is treating the first value '155973' as the total length thats why % contribution is 100%. While printing the second row it is taking the sum of '155973+154191' thats why % contribution is 49%. same procedure is followed till the end of the report. So the only correct % contribution value I m getting is for the 8th row.

It is showing the correct result for the last line only. I don't know how to do this. 
Please help.

Comment: Please post the current formula you're trying to use for "% Contribution" (and "Total Good Lgth(Mtr)" if there is one).

Comment: @Ryan I am using almost the same formula as Siva has written below. I am not getting that how to use the formula EvaluateAfter() ?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't mentioned what calculation you have developed and why its getting correct only for `Last Line`.... but general process is:

1. Place your data in details and take the summary for `report footer`.
2. Now create a formula `@Calculate` in that write below code:

   ```
   ToText(({Total good Lgth(MTR)}/Sum ({Total good Lgth(MTR)/}))*100) & " %"
   ```

Place the formula `@Calculate` beside the `Total good Lgth(MTR)` in detail section

Comment: I have also used the same type of calculation as you have mentioned, but it is taking the first value as "Total good Lgth(MTR)" and "Sum ({Total good Lgth(MTR)}". Thats why showing 100% in contribution.

Comment: ok then what is the result... where is the problem? what is your report structure?

Comment: Report runs row wise always, what i need is that the contribution column must be executed and printed in the end so that i have all the values of "Total good Lgth(MTR)". Then i can use a simple % formula to find the % Contribution

Comment: I didnt understand u r requirement can you edit your question on what exactly u r expecting

Comment: Crystal report always runs from left to write and top to bottom. I want to hold the value of % contribution till the time i get the total of 'Total good Lgth(MTR)'.

Comment: so the formula you have told me will not work in this situation The % contribution must be evaluated after the second column is printed completely till the 8th value because then only i will have have the sum as '1338595' which comes in the last row of second column.

Comment: @user3732694 it depends where you placed the fields and how are you calculating the summary?.... Solution I answered and you have used will work.. if that doesn't work you can use sub report... first calculate the summary and then pass the value to the sub report and use it anywhere in the sub report.

Comment: @Shiva It doesn't matter where i placed the field or how i calculate because 1st row will always be executed first then second then third so the solution u have answered will not work m sure. Anyways thanks